# Kendo UI Angular Grid NumberFormatOptions

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-ui-angular2, kendo-ui-grid

I understand there are a few ways to format the numbers in the Angular Kendo UI Grid.
For example:  `{{decimal | kendoNumber:'c' }}`

But instead of having a currency I would like to format the number in the following format (similar with the currency but without currency label):

123.123.123.123,11

(12 digits before the comma and two after the comma.)
In Kendo there are some [NumberFormatOptions](https://www.telerik.com/kendo-angular-ui/components/internationalization/api/NumberFormatOptions/) but I could not figure out how to use them. Can anyone provide me some examples of how to use these NumberFormatOptions correctly?

Would be great. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Additional information can be found here: https://github.com/telerik/kendo-intl/blob/master/docs/num-formatting/index.md

Comment: Awesome. That link explains a lot. Thanks. Just what I was looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try a 'n2' format option, it works in the same way but without currency symbol

```
{{ 123123123123.11  | kendoNumber:'n2' }}
```

Answer (score 0):

For the Kendo grid (e.g. to use currencies), the proper way to do this would be to import the language pack and provide it in your module:

> import '@progress/kendo-angular-intl/locales/en/all';
>
> { provide: LOCALE_ID, useValue: 'en' }

Then in your kendo grid:

> < kendo-grid-column field="Amount" title="Amount"
> width="150" format="{0:c}">